# How can I make people see my question?

Tags: discussion, unanswered-questions

I asked a question a while ago and got one answer, but I tried what it said to do and it didn't work.  I haven't gotten any more answers.  How can I make people see my question?  Is there a way to bump it back up to the top of the list?

Comment: Similar or the same: http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/8860/how-to-make-questions-noticeable-without-bounty?rq=1

Comment: If you comment on the answer saying it didn't work. This will get your question re-added to the recently active list, which can be accessed from the top of the questions page by clicking on "Active".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The best thing to do is to edit the question and add in more information. This shows you are still working on it.

Even if it is a couple of lines explaining you found this and that but it still did not fix it.